# How to Change the Background Color of modal-content of Bootstrap in Angular 4

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I want to change my bootstrap model background color of modal-content but I am unable to change the modal-content background color kindly help me.

{{'MEDIA_PAGE.media_materials_title' | translate}}

```
<app-asset></app-asset>
</modal-content>
<modal-footer >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" (click)="addModel.close()">{{'SHARED.Actions.cancel' | translate}}</button>
  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary yes-button" (click)="ManagePublishNews(newsItem.id,false);addModel.close()">{{'SHARED.Actions.confirm' | translate}}</button> -->
</modal-footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to overwrite the CSS for that element and use the !important keyword after the CSS to make sure it overwrites.
E.G:

```
.modal-content {
    background: #f9a81a !important;
    border: 1.5px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add style to the html like this

```
<modal-content style="background-color:red;">  </modal-content>
```